# How to change the state of a Vue variable in an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a vue component:

```
import {foo} from 'path';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
    };
  },
```

How can I create imported JavaScript function that takes an `inputValue`, modifies it, and then returns the updated state of the `inputValue` to the vue component?

I tried passing the `inputValue` as a parameter to the function `foo()`, changing its value inside the function, and returning it, but I got an `undefined` value.

I'm creating an external function because modifying **`inputValue`** is just a small part of the function, and I don't want my code to become cluttered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Vue [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables) for small applications or [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) if you have a lot of logic around your state.

Check the Vue Docs on

- [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables)
- [State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html)

Here is a very simple sample

```js
const { createApp, ref  } = Vue;

const useStore = (value) => {
    const input = ref(value);
    const add = () => input.value++;
    return { input, add }
}

const App = {
  setup() {
    const { input, add } = useStore(1);
    return { input, add }  
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  line-height: 2;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="input" /> <button @click="add()">+1</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling it on a method?

```
methods: {
    updateInputValue() {
      this.inputValue = foo(this.inputValue);
    },
  },
```

Example on updating the input:

```
  <div>
    <input v-model="inputValue" />
    <button @click="updateInputValue">Update Input Value</button>
  </div>
```